# how to cast set into list in this situation

Tags: java, spring, jsp

This is my controller:

```
private void setUniqueSignSize(List<TemplateMasterModel> templateTypeList, final Map<String, Object> model) {

    Set<String> signSizeList = new HashSet<String>();

    for(TemplateMasterModel templateType: templateTypeList) {
        signSizeList.add(templateType.getTemplateGrpCode());
    }

    model.put("signSizeList", signSizeList);

    //getPaperTypes(templateTypeList, signSizeList, model);

}
```

This is my jsp:

```
<table style="width:500px; margin-bottom: 10px;margin-left:50px;">
    <tr>
        <td class="requiredFieldIndicator">Sine Size</td>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="tempTypeName" id="tempTypeName" value="">

            <select name="signTypeDesc" id="signTypeDesc" onchange="setTemplChangeValue();" style="width: 200px">
            <%
                String changeY = "";
                if(request.getAttribute("changeY") != null){
                    changeY = String.valueOf(request.getAttribute("changeY"));
                }

                List<TemplateMasterModel> templateTypeList = (List) request.getAttribute("signSizeList");
                if(templateTypeList != null && templateTypeList.size() != 0){
                    if(templateTypeList.size() == 1)
                    {
                        if(changeY.equals("No"))
                        {
                            %><option value="Select">None Selected</option><%   
                        }
                        %>
                        <option value="<%=templateTypeList.get(0).getTemplateGrpCode()%>"><%=templateTypeList.get(0).getTemplateGrpCode()%></option>
                        <%
                    }
```

How can I convert a set, `signSizeList`, into a list?

Comment: [`new ArrayList(signSizeList)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(java.util.Collection))

Comment: Why do you want to change to a list, why not just use the set as-is?  If the only reason is that you want the only element, use `if (set.size() == 1) { Model model = set.iterator().next(); }`

Answer (score 0):

either you can go for

```
List templateTypeList  = new ArrayList((HashSet)request.getAttribute("signSizeList"));
```

or add all the elements of set to a new ArrayList using .addAll() method of List.